# Unable to run basic linux commands on Makefile

Tags: amazon-web-services, makefile, devops

I'm trying to run basic Linux commands inside a Makefile, but it fails stating that the file is not found. (the file do exists)
Can anyone suggest how to rectify this error?

```
.PHONY: Checking
Checking:
    ${INFO} "Checking"
    ls -ltr ****/scripts.py
```

Error:
ls: cannot access '****/scripts.py': No such file or directory

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what you expect `****/scripts.py` to do, but in `/bin/sh` means the same thing as `*/scripts.py` and presumably that doesn't exist, hence the error message you're seeing.

I guess you are hoping to use some fancy shell feature that does deep searching if you give multiple `*` characters.  However, make always uses `/bin/sh`, it never uses your specific shell (imagine what a disaster that would be for portability!) which is typically a POSIX standard shell.  In POSIX, filename globbing is quite simple and doesn't support multiple `*` to mean search subdirectories.

You either have to use `find` or similar instead:

```
ls -ltr `find . -name scripts.py`
```

Or specifically set your shell to whatever you want (note this causes your makefile to be non-portable to systems which don't have your shell):

```
SHELL := /bin/myshell
```